# How can multiply two value in sql in row and put the result in the another cell in the same row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have table called 'Task'

have four column (id , x, y  and x*y)

i only enter the values (id, x and  y)

need trigger or other thing when i entered the values calculate automatic the value 'x*y'

thanks ,

Comment: Which RDBMS? Oracle? SQL Server?

Comment: Check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *do* want a trigger (maybe the value can be changed later, and `x*y` is just the default?), then yes this *can* be done:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_task on task
instead of insert
as
    insert into task (id,x,y,[x*y] /* Really need to rename this */)
    select id,x,y,x*y from inserted
```

See [Use the inserted and deleted Tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

Comment: yes this i mean ,i do this but when i using select i select from task not from inserted  (Y)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can just plain use a [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx), no need for triggers;

```
CREATE TABLE task (
  id INT,
  x  INT, 
  y  INT,
  xy AS x*y);  -- xy will always be selected as x*y
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9452a/1).

Other databases have similar functionality, for example [Oracle's virtual columns](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Computed columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to achieve your goal.

```
CREATE TABLE Task(Id int, x int, y int, xy as x* y);
```